# Screen Rotation unable to start activity Null pointer exception

Tags: android, exception, orientation

When I run my app in landscape mode it has no issues nor does it have any issues in portrait mode until i try to add an item to one of my lists while still in portrait mode, where of which my app crashes.

any ideas on how to fix this??

here is the error I am getting as feedback in logcat....

```
03-08 13:30:50.201: D/AndroidRuntime(554): Shutting down VM
03-08 13:30:50.201: W/dalvikvm(554): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.ATG.C3FactSystemTabbed/com.ATG.EditActivities.AmenitiesEditActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at com.ATG.EditActivities.AmenitiesEditActivity.registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText(AmenitiesEditActivity.java:68)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at com.ATG.EditActivities.AmenitiesEditActivity.onCreate(AmenitiesEditActivity.java:61)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  ... 11 more
```

this is the line that throws the exception

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){      <-------
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
         . . . . . 
        }
  });
```

this is only thrown when I am in portrait mode, it never gets thrown unless i change the orientation before trying to add something to the list. And if i already have the view open to add something no matter how i change the orientation it won't force close.

okay so i checked the files again i had different names for the buttons i was referencing in different xml files. In other words in landscape i was calling the button btnSave and in the other i was calling it btnAmenitiesSave. Problem solved thanks everyone!!!!!!

Comment: could you add the code where the `NullPointerException` is raised? ( line 68 in `AmenitiesEditActivity` )

Comment: i think you are updating UI in any running thread..

Comment: I guess instead you're calling a method in a view that does not exist in the landscape or portrait layout

Comment: NullPointerExceptions point you to the exact line of code: at com.ATG.EditActivities.AmenitiesEditActivity.registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText(AmenitiesEditActivity.java:68)
03-08 13:30:50.229: E/AndroidRuntime(554):  at com.ATG.EditActivities.AmenitiesEditActivity.onCreate(AmenitiesEditActivity.java:61). On line 61 in onCreate you call AmenitiesEditActivity, which on line 68 gives the NPE.

Comment: here is the code that throws the null pointer but i don't understand why it will work in landscape but not portrait ...    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

Comment: Please, update your question with the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`btnSave` is set to `null` in portrait.

It means :

- btnSave is not assigned ( no `btnSave = findViewById(....)` )
- or the id `the_id` specified in `btnSave = findViewById(R.id.the_id)` does not exist in the portait layout

Comment: how do i make sure it exists in the portrait layout?

Comment: check the layout you're setting in the `onCreate(R.layout.yourlayout)` ( available in res/layout/ or res/layout-port ).Add the `onCreate` method in your question & the associated layout if you want a more detailed answer

Comment: I have layouts set in both of those that reference the same Save button id.

Comment: do you have defined the layout with the same name in res/layout-land ? And does it contain the save button id ?

Comment: problem solved had the name for the btn different in layout and portrait thanks a ton